# Extract LSB for assembly program

Tags: assembly

I am trying to write an assembly multiplication program. However I am having trouble with extracting the lsb of the multiplier since I can only use bitwise NOR, BEQ, and ADD instructions for this purpose. My first idea was to use a mask but this idea failed. I might just have the wrong mask. Can someone help me brainstorm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lsb = multiplier AND 0xFF
```

As you have only `NOR`, you can extract `AND` functionality out of it for example like this:

```
m' = multiplier NOR multiplier   ; m' = not(multiplier)
lsb = m' NOR 0xFFFFFF00          ; I assume 32bit native size, adjust mask by true desired bit size
      ; i.e. the second operand is NOT(0xFF)
```

(didn't verify it, so I would appreciate confirmation)

I used this page for a quick check of NOR values table to make sure my mind doesn't play tricks on me (again): http://www.randomterrain.com/atari-2600-memories-tutorial-robert-m-06.html#logical_nand_nor_xnor

Comment: We can't use not operations but you reminded me that NOR is universal gate so I constructed AND from three NORs. I am just learning this stuff so thank you.

Comment: @Benjee: yeah, in the detailed description I have "not" only in comments (explaining what I'm trying to achieve), not in actual "code", where I use only `nor` and pre-calculated constants.